# C# Syntax - Split String into Array by Comma, Convert To Generic List, and Reverse Order

Tags: c#, generics, syntax, ilist

What is the correct syntax for this:

```
IList<string> names = "Tom,Scott,Bob".Split(',').ToList<string>().Reverse();
```

What am I messing up?
What does TSource mean?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `List<T>.Reverse()` which returns `void`.

You could either do:

```
List<string> names = "Tom,Scott,Bob".Split(',').ToList<string>();
names.Reverse();
```

or:

```
IList<string> names = "Tom,Scott,Bob".Split(',').Reverse().ToList<string>();
```

The latter is more expensive, as reversing an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` involves buffering all of the data and then yielding it all - whereas `List<T>` can do all the reversing "in-place". (The difference here is that it's calling the `Enumerable.Reverse<T>()` extension method, instead of the `List<T>.Reverse()` instance method.)

More efficient yet, you could use:

```
string[] namesArray = "Tom,Scott,Bob".Split(',');
List<string> namesList = new List<string>(namesArray.Length);
namesList.AddRange(namesArray);
namesList.Reverse();
```

This avoids creating any buffers of an inappropriate size - at the cost of taking four statements where one will do... As ever, weigh up readability against performance in the real use case.

Comment: well elaborated, I really appreciated!

Answer (score 14):

I realize that this question is quite old, but I had a similar problem, except my string had spaces included in it. For those that need to know how to separate a string with more than just commas:

```
string str = "Tom, Scott, Bob";
  IList<string> names = str.Split(new string[] {","," "},
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The StringSplitOptions removes the records that would only be a space char...

Comment: This won't work if you had "Tom Cruise" instead just Tom

Answer (score 5):

```
List<string> names = "Tom,Scott,Bob".Split(',').Reverse().ToList();
```

This one works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>("Tom,Scott,Bob".Split(','));
names.Reverse();
```

Comment: I get the error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

Answer (score 1):

What your missing here is that .Reverse() is a void method.  It's not possible to assign the result of .Reverse() to a variable.  You can however alter the order to use Enumerable.Reverse() and get your result

```
var x = "Tom,Scott,Bob".Split(',').Reverse().ToList<string>()
```

The difference is that Enumerable.Reverse() returns an IEnumerable<T> instead of being void return

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to

1. Use multiple delimiters
2. Filter any empty strings
3. Trim leading/trailing spaces

following should work:

```
string str = "Tom Cruise, Scott, ,Bob | at";
IEnumerable<string> names = str.Split(new char[] {',', '|', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Output

- Tom
- Cruise
- Scott
- Bob
- at

Now you can obviously reverse the order as others suggested.