# How can I split a string with a string delimiter?

Tags: c#, string, split

I have this string:

```
"My name is Marco and I'm from Italy"
```

I'd like to split it, with the delimiter being `is Marco and`, so I should get an array with

- `My name` at [0] and
- `I'm from Italy` at [1].

How can I do it with C#?

I tried with:

```
.Split("is Marco and")
```

But it wants only a single char.

Comment: related   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315358/c-sharp-syntax-split-string-into-array-by-comma-convert-to-generic-list-and

Answer (score 628, accepted):

```
string[] tokens = str.Split(new[] { "is Marco and" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If you have a single character delimiter (like for instance `,`), you can reduce that to (note the single quotes):

```
string[] tokens = str.Split(',');
```

Comment: you can remove `string`: `.Split(new[] { "is Marco and" }, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: `new string[]` is redundant in that case, you could just use `new []`

Comment: Note the single quotes in str.Split(','); instead of str.Split(",");
It took me a while to notice

Comment: Me too regarding the single quotes... why is that necessary?

Comment: @user3656612 Because it accepts character (char), not a string. chars are surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: I don't understand why they in C# included a string.split(char) but not a string.split(string)... I mean there are both string.split(char[]) and string.split(string[])!

Comment: how to do it with the character `'` ? I tried this but it does not split

Comment: @GuidoG: If you have a problem with that then ask a new querstion on StackOverflow about it.

Comment: @GuidoG Just checked it with the expression message.Split(new[] { "'" }, StringSplitOptions.None) - everything works fine

Answer (score 38):

```
.Split(new string[] { "is Marco and" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Consider the spaces surronding `"is Marco and"`. Do you want to include the spaces in your result, or do you want them removed? It's quite possible that you want to use `" is Marco and "` as separator...

Answer (score 21):

You are splitting a string on a fairly complex sub string. I'd use regular expressions instead of String.Split. The later is more for tokenizing you text.

For example:

```
var rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("is Marco and");
var array = rx.Split("My name is Marco and I'm from Italy");
```

Answer (score 15):

Try [this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) instead.

```
string source = "My name is Marco and I'm from Italy";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"is Marco and"};
var result = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use the `IndexOf` method to get a location of the string, and split it using that position, and the length of the search string.

---

You can also use regular expression. A simple [google search](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) turned out with this

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {
  static void Main() {
    string value = "cat\r\ndog\r\nanimal\r\nperson";
    // Split the string on line breaks.
    // ... The return value from Split is a string[] array.
    string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, "\r\n");

    foreach (string line in lines) {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Read *[C# Split String Examples - Dot Net Pearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)* and the solution can be something like:

```
var results = yourString.Split(new string[] { "is Marco and" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a version of `string.Split` that takes an array of strings and a `StringSplitOptions` parameter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Comment: No, it takes an array of string.