# How to split certain parts of a string into different arrays

Tags: c#

Looking for a way to split the following (poker hand) string: C 14 C 13 C 12 C 11 C 10
So that I can store the suits seperately to the card values, how can I seperate the characters and integers, new to c# and this is probably easy as hell, but please explain it to me in a newbie friendly way cheers :)

Comment: First link in google http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: It seems you are looking for the String's split method.
check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx

Comment: also it's been asked a few times already. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928601/how-can-i-split-a-string-with-a-string-delimiter

Comment: Didn't you already ask this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316679/how-to-split-parts-of-string-into-2-different-arrays/32316803#32316803

Answer (score 0):

follow below code

```
string str = "C 14 C 13 C 12 C 11 C 10";

string[] mixArray = str.Split(' ');

List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
List<string> characters = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < mixArray.Length; i++)
{
    int tempInt;
    if (int.TryParse(mixArray[i], out tempInt))
        numbers.Add(tempInt);
    else
        characters.Add(mixArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a more Object Oriented approach.
First create your class 'Card' to store a single card inside

```
public class Card
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Suit { get; set; }
}
```

after this you can manage the string as follow

```
//Original string
string values = "C 14 C 13 C 12 C 11 C 10";
//this line will split your string in an array and will take out empty values if exists
var split = values.Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray(); ;

List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
string card= string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < split.Count() - 1; i += 2)
    {
        cards.Add(new Card() { Value = int.Parse(split[i + 1]), Suit = split[i] });
    }
```

After you have all the cards stored in a list that is more flexible than the array. I think could be better aproach.