# C# Get all string list items split

Tags: c#

I have a List of strings with the items such-

```
Titanic, Leonardo Decaprio  
Mission Impossible, Tom Cruise
```

Is there any way such that I can get only the first substring before the comma? In above case the expected output for `List<string>` should be -

```
Titanic
Mission Impossible
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I split a string with a string delimiter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928601/how-can-i-split-a-string-with-a-string-delimiter)

Comment: @MicroVirus Not a duplicate of it. The answer I got below was the one I was looking for.

Comment: It a duplicate. The only difference is that you want to do this for every element of the list. If you can't apply the answer in that duplicate (using `Split`) with how to do that for each element of the list, then you need to really get back to the basics of learning C#.

Comment: Okay, Thank you..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Split`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj1hLiOoLHNAhWkBcAKHXyzCDoQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.string.split(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHqx3_8pArbFO3N2mC42khDG79MSw&sig2=pK3khvsMs5AhUi94C2cXEw&bvm=bv.124817099,d.ZGg&cad=rja) method and then using [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) method get only the first part.

```
list.Select(x=> x.Split(',')[0]);
```

You can use [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Split`

```
list.Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(',')));
```

If you are not sure that every string contains comma you can check it, for example this way

```
list.Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(',') > 0 ? x.IndexOf(',') : x.Length))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to call `.ToList()` method otherwise it will not cast the resulting list into `List<string>` and `throw exception` because resulting list would of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>` and your's is of `List<string`

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Titanic, Leonardo Decaprio", " Mission Impossible, Tom Cruise" };
list = list.Select(x => x.Split(',')[0]).ToList();
```