# How do I save result in string of executed command

Tags: c#

As the title says how can I save in string the result of the executed command?

```
SendCommand("server.hostname");
```

My code:

```
public void SendCommand(string command)
{
    PacketModel packet = new PacketModel()
    {
        Identifier = 1,
        Message = command,
        Name = "RustManager"
    };
    string packetString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet);
    _webSocket.SendAsync(packetString, null);
}

public void GetServerHostname()
{
    SendCommand("server.hostname");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to my small reputation I cannot comment - which is what I would have done before that.

Normally methods that end on `Async` are async and return a `Task<T>` type.
Using the `await` keyword makes your method async which is why you have to mark it as `async` in the method head.
[Link to C#-Documentation on the await keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await)

It is really hard to say how to get your code running since I don't have alot of information but maybe this helps:

```
public async void SendCommand(string command)
{
   PacketModel packet = new PacketModel()
   {
     Identifier = 1,
     Message = command,
     Name = "RustManager"
   };
   string packetString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet);
   var result = await _webSocket.SendAsync(packetString, null);
}
```

EDIT 1:
After getting some new information here is my new answer:
You use [this](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/master/websocket-sharp/WebSocket.cs) class for your websocket. If you look at the signiture of the "SendAsync" method you can see, that it returns `void` (which means "nothing"). So you will not be able to "Store some kind of information" here. 
The method looks like this:

`public void SendAsync (string data, Action<bool> completed)
{ [...] }`

You will have to listen to the WebSocket and wait for a server-side response. It seems, that the library supports that via events:

`ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => {
    ...
  };`

So you can define an eventhandler to process the server-response.

> If you would like to get the message data, you should access e.Data or e.RawData property.
>   e.Data property returns a string, so it is mainly used to get the text message data.
>   ([source (GitHub Readme)](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp))

So to fullfil your wishes try the following:

1.) At initialization of your `_websocket` instance subscribe to the `.OnMessage`event with a corresponding event handler. ([Some information about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp))

2.) Send your message as you do it now with `SendAsync`

3.) If your server responds with a message to the network socket, the `OnMessage`event will fire and you will be able to get the Data from the Eventargument `e`

(I did not test this - but it should work since it is used this way in the examples)

Comment: When I use it your code it says operator await can not be used for void...

Comment: Well I need more information about your code. What type is `_websocket` and so on?

Comment: I am using this websocket https://github.com/PsychoTea/RustManager
same as that
What I am trying to do is to save command which I executed and convert it and save it to string or something...

Comment: I would appreciate your help. it is in folder RustManager->ServerManagement-> WebSocketConnection.cs
Using the websocket-sharp.dll

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you for the information.
I eddited my answer.

Comment: Sure, I have one more question. How to save this numbers to a string "55 FPS" how to save it to a string the 55 number it is a variable?

Comment: Well there are multiple ways to do that. If you know that you string *allways* looks exactly like that, you can do String-Splitting and then Convert the String into an Int. 

`

string fps_string = InputString.Split(' ')[0];


int fps = Int32.Parse(fps_string);

`
But be careful here. Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928601/how-can-i-split-a-string-with-a-string-delimiter) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)

Comment: Ok thanks. I have one more question and I think it is my last question.
How can I send public string Players; from WebSocketConnection.cs to MainForm.cs

Comment: Well there are multiple ways to do that. I think the best way would be to let the MainForm have a reference to the WebSocketConnection object and manage the WebSocket object from there. Then it can access all its public members.

Another way would be to use events. You could subscribe to some custom event in the websocket class that gets invoked when recieving data.