# How to remove Whitespce from stringArray formed based on whitespace

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string which contains value like.

```
90  524           000   1234567890       2207 1926    00:34     02:40  S
```

Now i have broken this string into string Array based on white-space.Now i want to create one more string array into such a way so that all the white-space gets removed and it contains only real value.

Also  i want to get the position of the string array element from the original string array based on the selection from the new string array formed by removing white space.

Please help me.

Comment: The method Trim() will help you.

Comment: I think [this][1] is what you are looking for...

hope it helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315358/c-sharp-syntax-split-string-into-array-by-comma-convert-to-generic-list-and

Comment: Hmm more complicated than it seems... what 'position' would you like? the index of the first char? the count of elements, e.g. the 3rd? etc etc... what if 524 is the second and the 5th and the 7th and the 10th element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` via `String.Split`.

```
var values = input.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

> [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx): The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty string

When the `Split` method encounters two consecutive white-space it will return an empty string.Using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will remove the empty strings and give you only the values you want.

You can also achieve this using `LINQ`

```
var values = input.Split().Where(x => x != string.Empty).ToArray();
```

---

Edit: If I understand you correctly you want the positions of the values in your old array. If so you can do this by creating a dictionary where the keys are the actual values and the values are indexes:

```
var oldValues = input.Split(' ');
var values = input.Split().Where(x => x != string.Empty).ToArray();

var indexes = values.ToDictionary(x => x, x => Array.IndexOf(oldValues, x));
```

Then `indexes["1234567890"]` will give you the position of `1234567890` in the first array.

Comment: OK .Its Working .Other query is how to search the elements of `var values` for their position into Orginal array with Whitespace having this code..`string[] arr= input.Split(' ');`

Comment: @user3816352 why do you need that ? do you want to find index of a particular item then use Array.IndexOf method

Comment: Yes i want index only.How to find that for the array elements without whitespace from that with whitepspace

Comment: I will as soon as I understand what you mean... can you clarify it ? an example would be helpful

Comment: I want index but values would be from the arraywithout whitespace but index i want to from the original one with whitespace that i got from my code `string[] arr= input.Split(' ');`

Comment: Am i clear Sir ,If not i will try again to specify me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] arr = str.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Note that i've also added tab character as delimiter. There are other white-space characters like the line separator character, add as desired. Full list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "90  524           000   1234567890       2207 1926    00:34     02:40  S  ";
s.Split(' ').Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
```

Comment: Split will create an array of strings. `Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))` will remove all the white space or null entries of the array.